# launch a pig script with php

Tags: php, bash, shell, apache-pig

I am learning Pig Latin, and I would like to know how to launch a pig script with PHP.

This is my line for launching the script :

```
pig -f ../testjava/calculs_routage.pig -param input=/user/hive/warehouse/tableRoutage/ -param output=/resultatsRequetes/obj1/resultatObj1 -param date1=2013-11-08T00:00:00.000Z -param date2=2013-11-15T00:00:00.000Z
```

I have a script I can launch in my shell (i'm root) and it works, I try to launch my pig script with a bash, and it works too.

But when I try using my php application (so my user is apache), it doesn't work. I tried to launch the pig script directly or with a bash but it failed. This is my line for launching the script :

```
$cmdTest = exec('pig -f ../testjava/calculs_routage.pig -param input=/user/hive/warehouse/tableRoutage/ -param output=/resultatsRequetes/obj1/resultatObj1 -param date1=2013-11-08T00:00:00.000Z -param date2=2013-11-15T00:00:00.000Z 2>&1');
```

I tried changing the user with sudo but it failed too.

**The bash script :**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -s -u root

pig -f ../testjava/calculs_routage.pig -param input=/user/hive/warehouse/tableRoutage/ -param output=/resultatsRequetes/obj1/resultatObj1 -param date1=2013-11-08T00:00:00.000Z -param date2=2013-11-15T00:00:00.000Z
```

I don't know where is the probleme, is it the user or the error with the log file ?? I tried to change the path of the log files in log4j properties but it's doesn't change anything.

**My error message :**

```
 sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo 
13/12/23 14:16:35 WARN pig.Main: Cannot write to log file: /var/www/html/phpmail/vue/pig_1387804595477.log 
2013-12-23 14:16:35,481 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.11.1-Intel (r16951) compiled Jun 19 2013, 17:26:05 
2013-12-23 14:16:35,734 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /var/www/.pigbootup not found 
2013-12-23 14:16:35,752 [main] WARN org.apache.pig.Main - Cannot write to log file: /var/www/html/phpmail/vue//calculs_routage.pig1387804595751.log 
2013-12-23 14:16:35,767 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. null 
2013-12-23 14:16:35,767 [main] WARN org.apache.pig.Main - There is no log file to write to. 
2013-12-23 14:16:35,767 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:394) 
at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:143) 
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:454) at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)
```

I don't know what to do, and i need this script which is very performant.

Thanks for reading this and perhaps for your help !
And Happy Holidays !!

Angélique

Comment: Did you even read the error message?  `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: Yes but I'm beginner in script/shell/bash, I try to do my best, and I didn't unsderstand what this error could means.

Comment: It's not as much about being a beginner but perhaps more about _attempting_ to solve a problem.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to be running these sorts of things as root.

You can SU to apache by using `su -s /bin/bash apache`.  Then get your script working as the apache user by giving the correct access to the logs, etc.

(Note: your apache user might be www-data or something else instead of apache, you can use `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` to check)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that my user needs the access on the logs and that it could be the reason why pig didn't launch. Now, It works, I give the right to write on the directory where there are the logs. Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite explanatory - you cannot use sudo in a shell script without terminal as it expects a user to enter the password.

It may help to use SUID bit instead or "expect" command (http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) to supply the password

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I can't, I resolve my problem. I'll remind this command if I need it one day.